# Strange behavior of Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

I noticed some strange behavior in Visual Studio:

If an executable (.exe) is not owned by "TrustedInstaller" and is located in the "System directory" (usually "C:\Windows\System32"),
some features don't work well: eg. System.IO.File.Exist("C:\Windows\System32\MyExecutable.exe") returns "False", also Shell("C:\Windows\System32\MyExecutable.exe"), fails.

Instead, if the owner is "TrustedInstaller", such as eg. "credwiz.exe"
the function System.IO.File.Exist("C:\Windows\System32\credwiz.exe") returns "True", and the function "Shell("C:\Windows\System32\credwiz.exe"), runs the program.

Please, note that "crediwiz.exe" does not have a digital signature.

It turns out to you too?

It is a "bug" of VS, or there is a hand of Windows Defender?

---

I don't understand what you mean.
Do you mean that if I use another product I get the same result?

I haven't tried, but I still don't understand the meaning, these are proper functions of VS.

I have the following routine:

```
Sub MySub()

    booResult = System.IO.File.Exist(X)
    
            ...
            
    Shell(X)
    
            ...
            
End Sub
```

If X = "C:\Windows\System32\MyExecutable.exe", MySub does not work, instead X = "C:\Windows\System32\credwiz.exe" MySub work well.

While, if I launch the programs from the CMD, or Powershell, both programs starting without problems.

Is everything clear now?

Comment: Your question is a programming question (i.e. the problem is with your code not Visual Studio).

Comment: I apologize, it did not enter as a comment. Too long.

For Daniel B

Yes, absolutely. The environment is Windows 10 Pro x64. The VS version is 2015 CE (free, but licensed).
The program "MyExecutable" work perfectly both from prompt or cmd script.
It is only VS that has a tantrum!